# How do I write this cross Join in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join

It should create a set of columns (ControlRange, SensorBias, SensorError, VDCurve, INSHalfCurve, INSSensCurve, ExogDEXCurve, InitGlucose) and all permutations of their values. I want the order given to be the order of permutation (permute through all values of ControlRange before incrementing SensorBias). I get syntax errors when running this in MySQL, which worked fine in SQL Server.

```
USE IMTsimulations
;WITH Five(num) AS
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
), Four(num) AS
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3
), Three(num) AS
(
  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2
), Two(num) AS
(
  SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6
)
-- ##INSERT INTO [dbo].[Parameters]
     -- (ControlRange, InitGlucose, ExogDEXCurve, INSSensCurve, INSHalfCurve, VDCurve, SensorError, SensorBias)
     -- ##(ControlRange, SensorBias, SensorError, VDCurve, INSHalfCurve, INSSensCurve, ExogDEXCurve, InitGlucose)
     -- USE the SELECT to enforce incrementation order

SELECT cr.[num] AS [ControlRange],
       sb.[num] AS [SensorBias],
       se.[num] AS [SensorError],
       vd.[num] AS [VDCurve],
       i_t.[num] AS [INSHalfCurve],
       i_s.[num] AS [INSSensCurve],
       exdex.[num] AS [ExogDEXCurve],
       initg.[num] AS [InitGlucose]    
FROM Two cr
CROSS JOIN Three initg
CROSS JOIN Five exdex
CROSS JOIN Five i_s
CROSS JOIN Four i_t
CROSS JOIN Four vd
CROSS JOIN Three se
CROSS JOIN Five sb
ORDER BY ControlRange, SensorBias, SensorError, VDCurve, INSHalfCurve, INSSensCurve, ExogDEXCurve, InitGlucose
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support `WITH` and does not use `[]` around identifiers (it uses backticks (`) instead). You will probably have to repeat the right `SELECT ... UNION ...` as a subquery for each join. Other than that `Cross join` is the default one if you do not specify any join conditions.

```
SELECT cr.num AS ControlRange,
       sb.num AS SensorBias,
       se.num AS SensorError,
       vd.num AS VDCurve,
       i_t.num AS INSHalfCurve,
       i_s.num AS INSSensCurve,
       exdex.num AS ExogDEXCurve,
       initg.num AS InitGlucose    
FROM (SELECT 0 as num UNION ALL SELECT 1) cr
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as num UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) initg
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as num UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) exdex
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as num UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) i_s
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as num UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) i_t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as num UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) vd
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as num UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) se
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 as num UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) sb
ORDER BY ControlRange, SensorBias, SensorError, VDCurve, INSHalfCurve, INSSensCurve, ExogDEXCurve, InitGlucose
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/27829 (hope I did not do any mistake when rewriting it)

You could instead create tables `Two`, `Three`, `Four` and `Five` if you use it often, but there is soe overhead in actually storing it.

Answer (score 1):

Build a single table of numbers:  `VALUES (1), (2), ..., (10)`

Then use it repeatedly with `WHERE n BETWEEN 1 AND ...`.